# Why is my Xoom showing up as a Windows Portable Device?

Tags: motorola-xoom, windows

I have connected my Xoom to a Windows XP64 machine, and it shows up in the device manager as a Windows Portable Device.  However, it does not show up in My Computer as a Windows Portable Device as the Motorolla site says it will.

I'm unable to access the files on the Xoom, although the device shows up in Windows Media Player as a device I can sync.  However, it tries to convert files to fit onto the tablet rather than just copy the files over like I'd like to do.

Is this how this device is supposed to work, or is there something going wrong with my PC?

Comment: The whole USB mass storage mounting paradigm was problematic; it seems the replacement idea hasn't been fully worked out yet...   If you have the SDK you can adb push files; if you are on the same wifi as the pc you could look into using something like FTP.

Comment: What version of Windows Media Player do you have? I think some people have been reporting that upgrading to WMP 11 helps if you aren't on it already. XP-64 is also kind of notorious for driver issues/quirks, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, some devices show up as Mass Storage devices, only when USB Debugging option is turned OFF. See if that helps.